# Trouble Getting the smartd Attributes of a Western Digital 4TB HHD

Tags: hard-drive, smart, smartctl

I am trying to get the smartd attributes of a Western Digital 4TB HHD model WD4001FYYG-01SL3. I would like to get the following attributes:

1. SMART 5 Reallocated Sectors Count
2. SMART 187 Reported Uncorrectable Errors
3. SMART 188 Command Timeout
4. SMART 197 Current Pending Sector Count
5. SMART 198 Uncorrectable Sector Count

The drive is attached to an LSI MegaRAID SAS 9361-8i RAID card.  I am using the command "smartctl -a -d megaraid,14 /dev/sdk" to get the attributes and very few are returned. I also cannot find a spec sheet online detailing the attributes the HHD model supports. Is it possible that the RAID card is preventing access to the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SAS disks have few SMART attributes  (health status, temperature and errors statistics) because they are server's disks. If server's​ disk wants to die it must do it quickly. 
So many SMART attributes is needed on desktop disks  because they want to survive when its death is starting.